# emacs: can't make abbrev-insert function works

Tags: function, emacs, elisp

I have much difficulty with the ***abbrev-insert*** build-in function.
I've read the definition of the function and tried several things, but I have always an error.

here are the commands I tried with their output:

```
(define-abbrev global-abbrev-table "a1" "so long output")
(abbrev-insert "a1")
OUTPUT: abbrev-insert: Wrong type argument: symbolp, "a1"
(abbrev-insert 'a1)
OUTPUT: eval: Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil
(abbrev-insert 'a1 nil 1 3)
OUTPUT: eval: Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil
(abbrev-insert 'a1 "so long output" 1 3)
OUTPUT: eval: Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. If someone may help me please :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass to `abbrev-insert` an actual abbrev:

```
(abbrev-insert (abbrev-symbol "a1" global-abbrev-table))
```

Just any random symbol won't do it: it has to be the particular symbol stored in the abbrev-table in which you're interested, hence the need for `abbrev-symbol`.

Comment: I defined "a1" in the table (see the first code line). It's not a random symbol. But I don't understand why your solution works cause `(type-of (abbrev-symbol "a1"))` returns `symbol` like `(type-of 'a1)`. So why my solution doesn't work? mystery. Anyway thank you very much Stefan, you reply solved my trouble

Comment: Of course `a1` is a symbol as well.  But it's *another* symbol.  A *symbol* on Elisp is an *object*, much like a record/struct/tuple with mostly 4 fields which can be accessed via the 4 accessors `symbol-value`, `symbol-function`, `symbol-plist`, and `symbol-name`.